# CSV input to R Forecast with dates via R studio?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, regression, forecasting

I have a very simple csv file I'm trying to experiment with different forecast methods on.

```
          Year   total UnemplRt
   1  12/31/2013    NA      7.1
   2  12/31/2012 39535      8.3
   3  12/31/2011 36965     10.0
   4  12/31/2010 36234     10.9
   5  12/31/2009 37918      8.5
   6  12/31/2008 42235      4.3
   7  12/31/2007 55698      3.7
   8  12/31/2006 58664      3.8
   9  12/31/2005 59674      4.7
   10 12/31/2004 51439      5.7
```

When I import it using R studio I get this list. (above) which simply has the list name. and Col headers that I don't seem to be able to reference.

I am a total newbie at R, but  I gather I should have a Dataframe and that the 1st column should be a date type. Don't know how to get there from here.. and then .. And is that the correct layout for input to forecast?

How to use forecast (Mutli-models) to use rows 10-4 to forecast "total" on 3 using the UnemplRt on 3 (which is known in advance and so on ie. 10-3 to forecast 2 and 10-2 to forecast 1) which of course will be the forecast for the upcoming year...  I've got it working from a straight Linear Regression in a spreadsheet, but it is coming out too high, so I'm looking for methods that will factor recent data better and pay attention to the curve rather than just straight-line .

This is horribly simplistic but hopefully generic enough that others will find the answer useful as well.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to build a model for predicting your time series data or how to import the data and interpret the structure R created?

Comment: About your output: If you call `str(yourdata)`, you will see that you have indeed a data.frame with three columns. You should be able to reference your values with e.g. `yourdata$total`.

Comment: StatewideProjectiontest$total
NULL'data.frame': 11 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 11 levels "12/31/2004,51439,5.7",..: 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 ...

Comment: Thilo it is two part, can't build anything unless I can input the data, how to format the data to be able to provide it as input to forecast to build a model. It seems that forecast package should be able to try a several ways to fit the data?

Comment: Ok, I found this after recreating my little mess:>     class(StatewideProjectiontest)
[1] "data.frame"
> attributes(StatewideProjectiontest)
$names
[1] "Year"     "total"    "UnemplRt"

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
so now I'm just trying to format it correctly to hand it to forecast()

Comment: Now I have dates! StatewideProjectiontest$Year <- (as.Date(StatewideProjectiontest$Year, "%m/%d/%Y"))
> StatewideProjectiontest$Year
 [1] "2013-12-31" "2012-12-31" "2011-12-31" "2010-12-31"
 [5] "2009-12-31" "2008-12-31" "2007-12-31" "2006-12-31"
 [9] "2005-12-31" "2004-12-31"

Comment: S, I think I "should" be able to feed this Dataframe (or components) to forecast or forecast.Arima but I have no idea how to format the arguments. ie what do I use for "object" which I would assume to be the Year column and the total column (which is the column I'm trying to forecast, much less some other suggested parameters? and I think my regression parameter or xreg should be the UnemplRt? but again how to specify?

Comment: Guess I'm really wanting to feed the data to auto.arima  but do not know how to format the arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking about, but I assume that you would like to create some time series model with some regression included in it. Below an overview of building a simple time series model and one with a regressor included.

```
# load the base data as presented in the question
Workbook1 <- structure(list(Year = structure(1:10, .Label = c("31-Dec-04", 
"31-Dec-05", "31-Dec-06", "31-Dec-07", "31-Dec-08", "31-Dec-09", 
"31-Dec-10", "31-Dec-11", "31-Dec-12", "31-Dec-13"), class = "factor"), 
    total = c(51439L, 59674L, 58664L, 55698L, 42235L, 37918L, 
    36234L, 36965L, 39535L, NA), UnemplRt = c(5.7, 4.7, 3.8, 
    3.7, 4.3, 8.5, 10.9, 10, 8.3, 7.1)), .Names = c("Year", "total", 
"UnemplRt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

# Make a time series out of the value
dependent <- ts(Workbook1[1:9,]$total, start=c(2004), frequency=1)

# load forecast package
require(forecast)

# make a model that fits, you can get other models as well. Think it is best to some studying of the forecast package documentation.
fit <- auto.arima(dependent)

# do the actual forecast
fcast <- forecast(fit)

# here some results of the forecast
fcast
     Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
2013          39535 31852.42 47217.58 27785.501 51284.50

# You can make a plot as following:
plot(fcast)
```

As you are including some unemployment rate figures I assume that you might want to include this in your forecast in some sort of a regression model. Below a model about how you can approach this:

```
# load independent variables in variables.
unemployment <- ts(Workbook1[1:9,]$UnemplRt, start=c(2004), frequency=1)
unemployment_future <- ts(Workbook1[10:10,]$UnemplRt, start=c(2004), frequency=1)

# make a model that fits the history
fit2 <- auto.arima(dependent, xreg=unemployment)

# generate a forecast with the already known unemployment rate for 2013.
fcast2 <- forecast(fit2,xreg=unemployment_future)
```

Here the result of the forecast, again you can make a plot of it as above.

```
fcast2
     Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2013       45168.02 38848.92 51487.12 35503.79 54832.25
```

Hopes the above helps.

Comment: Fantastic! just what I was trying to do,, I guess among other issues, my attempt at formatting a DF was wacky. In terms of forecast 2 which value is the mean value? 45,168? I guess...

Comment: Curious, this exactly the same value as I got doing a simple straight-line regression. What I was hoping was to weight the more recent data more as I "feel" that the projected increase is too high, as it was last year using the same method. so weighting more recent data should bring the last year projection and this closer? (hope that makes sense)

Comment: @dartdog Make sure you plot the data with `plot(fcast2)` and you see it visual. The dot is the 45168 and is the so-called point forecast the other numbers indicate the low and high of the confidence intervals (80% and 90%). It doesn't surprise me that the model gives you more or less the same as your regular regression model; especially given the result of forecast 1 (a straight line). The auto.arima model is a special kind of model, but make sure you check the various models available in the forecast package.

Comment: I continued this exercise on Cross Validated, more great help on refining the model and using R http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46568/arima-regression-improving-the-model/46575#46575